# how can I scrapd email addresses from webpage with bash with wget?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, security

Hey im trying to scrapd emails from this webpage but i keep getting an error, here is the code

`wget -q -r -l 5 -O - https://ahrefs.com/blog/find-email-address/ | grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b"`

my output: -k or -r can be used together with -O only if outputting to a regular file.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you using curl instead?

```sh
curl --silent https://ahrefs.com/blog/find-email-address/ | grep -Eo '\w*[.]?\w*@\w*[.]\w*'
```

edit: The regex pattern used here doesn't always work, so if someone has a better one, please share.